# CoreData ensure combination of related objects is unique

Tags: swift, core-data, relational-database

NOTE: I deleted, then reposted this because the solution I thought I had doesn't work quite as expected.

**Original Post:**
I have a CoreData table that acts to bind different objects to each other.

[image]

How can I ensure that the specific combination of in this case challenge and team is a unique combination?

The idea here is that a team views a challenge, which presents a series of videos for them to pick from (this happens in the DBChallenge object, which has a playlist of videos. The user picks one or more videos they see as answers to the challenge, and that is stored in Answer.videos (to-many), in case that makes it clearer.

**Since Original Post:**
I set constraints as shown : [image]

This seems to constrain it to either the challenge, or the team, but not the combination, or perhaps I'm wrong. How is a constraint constructed to unsure that the specific combination of two relationship one-to-one values is unique?

Comment: I don’t think you can create a constraint like this in the model, you need to do it in code.